# MLeap and Spark ML SQLTransformer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, mleap

I have a question. I am trying to serialize a PySpark ML model to mleap.
However, the model makes use of the SQLTransformer to do some column-based transformations e.g. adding log-scaled versions of some columns.
As we all know, Mleap doesn't support SQLTransformer - see here : 
https://github.com/combust/mleap/issues/126
so I've implemented the former of these 2 suggestions:

- For non-row operations, move the SQL out of the ML Pipeline that you
  plan to serialize
- For row-based operations, use the available ML
  transformers or write a custom transformer <- this is where the
  custom transformer documentation will help.

I've externalized the SQL transformation on the training data used to build the model, and I do the same for the input data when I run the model for evaluation.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to obtain the same results across the 2 models.
Model 1 - Pure Spark ML model containing

```
SQLTransformer + later transformations : StringIndexer -> 
OneHotEncoderEstimator -> VectorAssembler -> RandomForestClassifier
```

Model 2 - Externalized version with SQL queries run on training data in building the model. The transformations are 
everything after SQLTransformer in Model 1:

```
 StringIndexer -> OneHotEncoderEstimator -> 
 VectorAssembler -> RandomForestClassifier
```

I'm wondering how I could go about debugging this problem. Is there a way to somehow compare the results after each stage to see where the differences show up ?
Any suggestions are appreciated.